# 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll when connect to MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am new on C# and mongoDB. I write a simple code for connecting vs to MongoDB. but when i run the program I got this error "

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

this is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver.GridFS;

namespace MongoDbTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017";

        MongoClient oClient = new MongoClient(connectionString);

        MongoServer oServer = oClient.GetServer();

        MongoDatabase db = oServer.GetDatabase("dblearnfiles");

        MongoCollection<BsonDocument> collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("user");

        foreach (var item in collection.FindAll())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
        }
        Console.WriteLine("LearnFiles");
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
}
```

I got error in this line:

```
 MongoClient oClient = new MongoClient(connectionString);
```

oClient is null!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **solved** that.
I changed this code into :

```
            var client = new MongoClient();
        var db = client.GetDatabase("dblearnfiles");
        var coll = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("user");

        foreach(var item in coll.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToList())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

and worked.